# Can mercury inhalation from dental amalgams cause Alzheimer's disease?

Tags: medical-science, mercury

We can [read here](http://www.ilpi.com/safety/mercury.html):

> In fact, some scientists believe that vapor inhalation from dental amalgams can cause Alzheimer's disease in certain genetically predisposed individuals, although the safety of dental amalgams is still a topic of hot debate.

Comment: It should be noted that (as stated in the article) the hazards of amalgam in general are notable mainly when considering dental workers, who can absorb more of the metal in one day than the patient in a year.

Comment: Le Iene (an Italian tv program) mentioned this issue in [one of their episodes](https://www.iene.mediaset.it/video/pasca-quando-un-otturazione-ti-cambia-la-vita_70492.shtml) in 2016, even though I beileve they cite multiple negative effects, not just Alzheimer's.

Comment: If amalgam generates mercury vapour then that should be easy to measure.  Just put some in a test tube, warm to body temp, and connect to a mass spectrometer.

Answer (score 12):

The Alzheimer's Association has declared that "[silver dental fillings increase risk of Alzheimer's disease](https://www.alz.org/alzheimers-dementia/what-is-alzheimers/myths)" is a myth (see below; emphasis added).

> Many scientists consider the studies below compelling evidence that **dental amalgam is not a major risk factor for Alzheimer's**. Public health agencies, including the FDA, the U.S. Public Health Service and the World Health Organization, endorse the continued use of amalgam as safe, strong, inexpensive material for dental restorations.

From the [Food and Drug Administration (FDA)](https://www.fda.gov/medicaldevices/productsandmedicalprocedures/dentalproducts/dentalamalgam/ucm171117.htm#6) (emphasis added):

> In an effort to obtain new information that might improve understanding or change risk estimates for the use of dental amalgam, twenty-four peer-reviewed scientific articles--published primarily since the reviews conducted by ATSDR and EPA--and ten peer-reviewed articles from the ATSDR and/or EPA reviews deemed to contain important and relevant information were critically reviewed. Compared to previous analyses performed by USPHS, no significant new information was discovered from the review of these 34 articles that would change the risk estimates by FDA for the use of dental amalgam. **It is concluded that there is insufficient evidence to support an association between exposure to mercury from dental amalgams and adverse health effects in humans, including sensitive subpopulations.**

Presumably, the lack of "adverse health effects in humans, including sensitive subpopulations" would include a lack of Alzheimer's disease.

From the [U.S. Public Health Service](https://health.gov/environment/amalgam1/amalgamr.htm):

> There is no evidence at present that the health of people with amalgam is compromised in any way.

From the [World Health Organization](https://www.fdiworlddental.org/resources/policy-statements-and-resolutions/who-consensus-statement-on-dental-amalgam) (emphasis added):

> **Dental amalgam restorations are considered safe**, but components of amalgam and other dental restorative materials may, in care [sic] instances, cause local side effects or allergic reactions. **The small amount of mercury** released from amalgam restorations, especially during placement and removal, **has not been shown to cause any other adverse health effects**.

[This 2003 study](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMra022471) states (emphasis added)

> Several  epidemiologic  investigations **failed to provide evidence** of a role of amalgam  in  [degenerative  diseases such as  amyotrophic lateral sclerosis, **Alzheimer’s disease**, multiple sclerosis, and Parkinson’s disease.

Finally, [these scientists](https://jada.ada.org/article/S0002-8177(14)65713-5/fulltext) have wrote (emphasis added):

> The authors found **no significant association of AD with** the number, surface area or history of having **dental amalgam restorations**. They also found no statistically significant differences in brain Hg level between subjects with AD and control subjects.

The American Dental Association has a page titled [Dental Amalgam: What Others Say](https://www.ada.org/en/press-room/press-kits/dental-fillings-press-kit/dental-amalgam-what-others-say) that includes statements by many entities attesting that dental amalgams do not have adverse health effects.

To summarize:

> Can vapor inhalation from dental amalgams cause Alzheimer's disease?

**No, vapor inhalation from dental amalgams do not cause Alzheimer's disease.** This is the official opinion of all organizations I looked up and has been shown in scientific studies.

Comment: @matt I recently learned that amalgam use *was* declining, but it seems to have been holding at about 50% for the last 20 years or so. https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/18914/what-percentage-of-fillings-performed-today-are-done-with-mercury-amalgam

Comment: Regarding AD increasing, that could be a diagnosis increasing rather than incidence.

Comment: @fredsbend Nice to see data on the worldwide use of amalgam. My original comment was based on my experiences in Europe whereas your data shows, some countries have completely eliminated it (the USA is often an outlier in anything to do with healthcare).. This provides an interesting long term test for believers in the AD-Hg relationship: is AD now rarer in Europe than this is in the USA (as far as I know it isn't)?

Comment: @matt_black Thank you for the clarification. Makes sense now.

Comment: Well you actually lost of opinions against theory instead of telling more about it and how it is justified.

Comment: @Croll Could you expand on your thought? Thanks!

Comment: It is more valued to understand _how_ inhalation of smth. could cause Alzheimer, instead of reading opinions who deny this possibility because question already assumes this theory is not popular. If there is no information on _how_, then this is possibly the most significant counter argument already. Still thank you.

Comment: @Croll This method wasn't very popular in the community. Check older versions of the answer for what you are interested in.

Comment: @Croll: Opinions about what mechanism there might be for X to cause Y are valueless if there is evidence that X doesn't cause Y.

Comment: Don't confuse evidence and [common knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_knowledge). Such questions contain assumptions to be investigated, verified - "why there was such a guess?". It is organic way of thinking.

Comment: @Croll: This answer contains evidence, from peer-reviewed papers, that there is no significant association between AD and dental amalgams. That has nothing to do with "common knowledge", "opinions" and/or whether a "theory is not popular". Describing why people how people came up with the conjecture or why they propagate them in the face of evidence (and "organic" thinking) is not required to address the question..